# how to calculate integrate about Heaviside

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

everyone,here I have a question about how to calculate
 $$\int e^t H(t) dt$$
where $H(t)$ is Heaviside step function
thank you for your answering!!

Comment: Try splitting the integral into two parts, either side of zero.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int f(t) H(t), dt = \int_0^{+\infty} f(t)
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The Heaviside function is defined as
\begin{aligned}
\text{H}(t) & = 0, \quad t<0,\\
\text{H}(t) & = 1, \quad t\geq0.
\end{aligned}
That means your integrand will be zero for all $t<0$, and $e^{t}$ for $t\geq1$. Can you figure out the rest?

**Note:** If you use the half-maximum convention though, you will find it to be:
\begin{aligned}
\text{H}(t) & = 0, \quad t<0,\\
\text{H}(t) & = \frac{1}{2}, \quad t=0,\\
\text{H}(t) & = 1, \quad t>0.
\end{aligned}
If so, you will have the integrand is $\frac{1}{2}e^{t}$ in $t=0$, and the rest is similar to the above.

Comment: use computer to solve,I find answer:(e^t-1)*H(t)

Comment: However,use integration by part,int e^t*H(t) dt=int H(t) d(e^t)=e^t*H(t)-int e^t d(H(t))= e^t*H(t)-delta(t)*e^t

Comment: where delta(t) is dirac-delta function,so I still can't understand why there is a subtle difference between computer and my answer from Integrantion By Part

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5Et*H%28t%29+dt

Comment: Don't forget that you are integrating over the Dirac-delta function (it doesn't make much sense otherwise), which means that you evaluate the integrand in the point where the delta function has a zero argument. Just like you wrote: $I = \int e^{t} \text{H}(t) dt = e^{t}\text{H}(t) - \int e^{t} \frac{d}{dt}\left(\text{H}(t)\right)dt$ where $\frac{d}{dt}\text{H} = \delta(t)$, so $I = (e^{t}-1)\text{H}(t)$. The last integral turns into $\text{H}(t)e^{0}$ instead of just $e^{0}$, since the original expression is zero for all $t<0$.

Comment: If we are using the half-maximum convention, do we just have $\int_0^b f(x)H(x)dx = f(b)-\frac{1}{2}f(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative that you need is zero in the negatives and an exponential in the positives. Hence take a constant in the negatives and an exponential in the positives.

$$H(-x)+e^xH(x)$$ will be continuous. No solution can be differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the result is just trivially

$\int e^tH(t)~dt=e^tH(t)+C$